# How to setforce at a constant interval?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I use gazebo7.12.0 and want to write a model plugin to apply torque to a joint at a constant interval of 0.01 sec. It seems that the update rate of gazebo is 1000Hz, so I wirte the following code in OnUpdate(). This is not a good way because it's not exact 1000Hz in simulation from my testing. Is there other way to do it?

```
int count = 0;
public: void OnUpdate()
{
  if (count <= 10)
     this->model->GetJoint("joint")->SetForce(0,5);
  else if (count > 10 && count <= 20)
     this->model->GetJoint("joint")->SetForce(0,5);
  ...
  count++;
};
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19672/how-to-setforce-at-a-constant-interval?/) by [jwchang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5575/jwchang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Why do you say it's not at 1000 Hz? Try changing the callback to `OnUpdate(const common::UpdateInfo &_info)` and print `_info.simTime`.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwchang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5575/jwchang/) on 2018-06-13**:
Thank you. I change my code to store the torque values into an array, which is SetForce(0,torque[count++]); usleep(10000);, and it works.